# XSLT-1.0 Setting node name as value in different node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I amusing xslt-1.0 to convert below input.xml to output.xml. I am facing difficulty in getting node name as value for different node. Please find below input.xml and help me to get output.xml. Thanks in advance.

Please note that some node values are rich text data and some are not.

input.xml:

```
<Presentation>
<MainDescription>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p><img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg" width="322" height="100"/></p>
    ]]>
</MainDescription>
<KeyConsiderations>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
        <p><img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg" width="322" height="100"/></p>
        <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
    ]]>
</KeyConsiderations>
<Skills>
    <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
</Skills>
<Synonyms>
    <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
</Synonyms>
</Presentation>
```

output.xml:

```
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
    <THE-VALUE>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1>Main Description</h1>
               <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
               <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
               <p><img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166?accept=none&amp;private" width="322" height="100"/></p>
            <h1>Key Consideration</h1>
               <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
               <p><img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166?accept=none&amp;private" width="322" height="100"/></p>
               <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <h1>Skills</h1>
               <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
               <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
               <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <h1>Synonyms</h1>
               <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you have so far?

Comment: I am afraid parsing stuff like `<img alt=" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"` where the `alt` attribute has an opening quote and then no closing would be even difficult in XSLT 2 or 3. I am not sure how you expect to parse stuff like that to manipulate/transform it (e.g. add `class="embeddedImageLink"` attributes) in any language, unless you have access to some error correcting parser like an HTML5 parser.

Comment: Apologies. With alt it is typo. alt="" has both opening and closing quotes. With respect to class attribute, I think you can skip that. For better understanding I corrected the input.xml & output.xml. I hope this make it easier. Hoping for your favorable response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to unescape the contents of those elements. This can be done with `disable-output-escaping` - if your XSLT processor supports it (browser-integrated processors usually don't, stand-alone processors usually do).

For example this template:

```
<xsl:template match="MainDescription">
    <h1>Main Description</h1>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

would turn `<MainDescription>` from your sample to:

```
<h1>Main Description</h1>

        <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p><img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg" width="322" height="100"/></p>
```

Create more such templates for the other elements.

---

Without `disable-output-escaping`, the output of the template would be this:

```
<h1>Main Description</h1>

        &lt;p&gt;Line1 The main description text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Line2 The main description text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt="" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg" width="322" height="100"/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

which is 100% equivalent to the initial `CDATA` section, it's just another way to write it. BTW, this is not "rich text". It's text, nothing more. Text that happens to contain a few angle brackets.